# Importing an Excel file as a structured dataset

Tags: import, dataset, excel

I need to import an Excel file as a dataset with row and column headers, and the following option using "Dataset" does not work.  However, I can import the Excel file using "Data" option as a list with no error.

```
adata = Import["Adata.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}]
```

> ```
> Import::noelem: The Import element "Dataset" is not present when importing as XLSX.
> $Failed
> ```

```
bdata = Import["Adata.xlsx", {"Data", 1}]
```

> ```
> {{"No", "y1", "y2", "y3", "VIN"}, {10., 4., 5., 9., "x1"}, {11., 3., 
>   6., 10., "x2"}, {12., 2., 7., 11., "x3"}, {13., 1., 8., 12., 
>   "x4"}, {14., 0., 1., 2., "x5"}}
> ```

Then, I can use the Dataset function to change the list to a dataset but don't know how to set the first row and the first column as the column and the row headers.  I read the documents for Import with no success.

```
bdata = Dataset[Import["Adata.xlsx", {"Data", 1}]]
```

Thanks.

Sangdon

Comment: `Import["Adata.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}` and `Import["Adata.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}, "HeaderLines" -> {1, 1}]` works as expected in version 11.3 (windows 10/64bit).

Answer (score 3):

```
imp = Import["Adata.xlsx", {"Data", 1}]; 
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[imp[[2 ;;, 1]] -> 
   (AssociationThread[imp[[1, 2 ;;]] -> #] & /@ imp[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]])]]
```

[image]

`Import["Adata.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}]` also works:

```
Import["Adata.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}, "HeaderLines" -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I read the documents and found the exact example in the "import option", however, strangely enough, the exact command does not work.  I am using 11.2.            https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XLSX.html?view=all.    Thanks again.  Sangdon

Comment: @Sangdon, if your OS is windows10, it might be a glitch that is fixed in version 11.3.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes.  I believe the "Dataset" option not working is a glitch in 11.2.  I use windows 10 and 11.2.

Answer (score 2):

I think `SemanticImport` might work well. I don't have Excel, so I made an .xlsx file from your sample data and imported it with `SemanticImport` as proof of concept.

Here is the code:

```
data = 
  {{"No", "y1", "y2", "y3", "VIN"}, 
   {10., 4., 5., 9., "x1"}, 
   {11., 3., 6., 10., "x2"}, 
   {12., 2., 7., 11., "x3"}, 
   {13., 1., 8., 12., "x4"}, 
   {14., 0., 1., 2., "x5"}};

path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "data.xlsx"}];
Export[path, data];

ds = 
  SemanticImport[
    path, 
    Join[ConstantArray[Automatic, 4], {"String"}], 
    HeaderLines -> 1]
```

[image: dataset]

Comment: Thanks.  I found that the "Dataset" option not working is a glitch in 11.2 and fixed in 11.3.  I start learning the MMA few month ago and love that I can solve ODE with easy.